# In convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ it is true that $\angle ADB = 2\angle ACB$ and $\angle BDC = 2 \angle BAC$. Prove that $AD=CD$

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

Let $E$ be such point on line $AD$ that $ED=CD$. This implies that triangle $EDC$ is iscocles, so $\angle DEC=\alpha+\beta$. Therfore $\angle CEA+\angle CBA=180^o$ and quadrilateral $ABCE$ is inscribed in circle. Since $\angle CDA=2\angle AEC$, $D$ then $D$ is center of a circle, so $DC=AD$.
[image]

Is this proof correct? Because fact that you can swap angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and it would still work bothers me and it does not feel rigorous.

Comment: Proof looks correct to me, very nice :)

Comment: Just stating $\angle CDA = 2 \angle AEC$ is not good enough to show D is center of the circle. If $AE$ is another chord and not a diameter, $\triangle CDE$ can still be made isosceles triangle and that will make $\angle CDA = 2 \angle AEC$. But with other given angles, yes. So you have to complete the argument. Alternatively, draw $BE$. Now $\angle BEA = \angle BCA = \alpha$. As $\angle ADB = 2 \alpha, \angle DBE = \alpha$. So $DE = BD = CD$. So $\angle BCD = 90^0 - \beta$ and now you can show $\angle ACE = 90^0$ so $AE$ is diameter.

Comment: I do not think the proof is good. I think you need to start with an assumption that a solution exist where the segment are not equal and than show that the angel requirement can be met only if the segments are equal. The circle need to be a result of the proof.

Comment: @Moti you may suggest another way but to say the method OP has adopted is not good would be taking it too far. A cyclic quadrilateral construction is a a good way to prove it. Yes his deduction of $D$ being the center was not backed up completely and he would need to fix that.

Comment: I did not see in the question that it is said that ABCD is a cyclic quadrilateral - I think it is needed to be proved.

Comment: @Moti ABCD is not cyclic quadrilateral, but ABCE is because I constructed it to be in the way that is described in post

Comment: You need to show that there is only one point on AE that fulfils the requirement as stated to make this complete. The center clearly does it but is only the center do it? Hope I clarified my comment.